# JavaScript d3.csv() gives Error: read ECONNRESET

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to test d3's d3.csv() csv reading function but still getting an error

`{ 'Error: read ECONNRESET': '    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)' }`

My test script `test1.js` is in react app directory.

```
admin:reactStockCharts jvr23$ tree -L 1
.
├── BCHARTS-BITSTAMPUSD.csv
├── README.md
├── node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── public
├── reactStockCharts.sublime-project
├── reactStockCharts.sublime-workspace
├── src
└── test1.js
```

Testing csv file `BCHARTS-BITSTAMPUSD.csv` resides in the same directory. The content is as follows:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume (BTC),Volume (Currency),Weighted Price
2017-07-11,2326.12,2399.0,2242.62,2336.78,16815.9742946,39367980.6825,2341.10614068
2017-07-10,2504.0,2527.88,2261.85,2323.45,17296.3404527,41650843.7716,2408.07261429
2017-07-09,2550.13,2564.65,2500.5,2502.28,4483.14413363,11362427.9698,2534.47750755
2017-07-08,2501.46,2555.0,2462.0,2550.07,5405.89088691,13584489.5168,2512.90486637
2017-07-07,2599.01,2605.0,2475.0,2501.46,9430.6154578,23870564.3605,2531.17778658
```

`test1.js` script content:

```
var d3 = require("d3");

d3.csv("BCHARTS-BITSTAMPUSD.csv", function(err, data) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(data[0]);
});
```

Executing the script then gives

```
admin:reactStockCharts jvr23$ node test1.js 
null
{ 'Error: read ECONNRESET': '    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)' }
```

The d3 package was installed sucessfully via `$ npm i d3` before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by replacing

```
var d3 = require("d3");

d3.csv("BCHARTS-BITSTAMPUSD.csv", function(err, data) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(data[0]);
});
```

with full path specification

```
var d3 = require("d3");

d3.csv("file:///full/path/to/BCHARTS-BITSTAMPUSD.csv", function(err, data) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: You mean specifying a `local` path?? If so, what would happen if you go live?

Comment: I just needed to get some sample csv data to react-stockchart components. This solution isn't gonna be live.

Answer (score 0):

```
var d3 = require("d3");

d3.csv("file:///full/path/to/BCHARTS-BITSTAMPUSD.csv", function(err, data) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(data);
});
```

is not a solution for when you want to deploy it online, because the path will change. You should use a relative path, as explained here: https://coderwall.com/p/8nhqeg/relative-paths-from-the-root-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`path`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module to get absolute URL

```
var path = require("path");
var d3 = require("d3");

d3.csv(path.resolve("BCHARTS-BITSTAMPUSD.csv"), function(err, data) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(data);
});
```